# How do i programatically open a closed TabItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have dxdo:DocumentPanel in my application and it contains many TabItems, and these TabItems are called from the Buttons. If user closes any of the TabItem and then he clicks on the respective button of closed tab i want to reopen this closed tab. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

TabControl SelectedIndex or SelectedValue

[TabControl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)